# Why the word Programming in LPP

Tags: optimization, terminology, computer-science, linear-programming

Why is Linear Programming Problem called so? I get the linear Problem but why the word programming?
Note : I'm don't know anything related to Computer Science (even basics) and I think the word programming is related to Computer Science isn't it the case?

Comment: One definition of the word “programming” is “the action or process of scheduling something, especially radio or television programs.” An early application of linear programming was logistics or scheduling stuff.

Comment: A historical explanation (as mentionned by littleO):  The group "linear programming" has been coined in the late 40s in a time where the single word "programming" hadn't been yet coined.

Comment: I think it was Bellman who coined the "programming" term. He appears to have chosen the used the word "programming" due to political/funding reasons. As Bellman writes:
"...what name, could I choose? In the first place I was interested in planning, in decision making, in thinking. But planning, is not a good word for various reasons. I decided therefore to use the word, “programming”..."

https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~cis520/dynamic/2021/wiki/index.php?n=Notes.DP